# React - When user search an API in form, how to handle no matches in API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, validation, fetch-api

I'm trying to build an weather application for a school project in React. I've gotten so far  that when I search for London, it will show me the current temperature and other useful information I've chosen to display. I simply want a message to appear that the city could not be found, I guess this somehow should done in a variable and with help of `if` statements?

However I'm not sure how I handle if the user types something that that isn't there, for example "new jorc" instead of New York. My current code looks like this:

```
getWeather = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const city= e.target.elements.city.value;

  if(city){
    const api_call = await fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`
    );
  
    const response = await api_call.json();

    this.setState({
      city: `${response.name}`,
      celsius: this.evenDeagree(response.main.temp),
      wind: this.evenDeagree(response.wind.speed),
      feelsLike: this.evenDeagree(response.main.feels_like)
      
      });

} else{
   this.setState({error: true})
 }
```

Any aid is appreciated.

Comment: check `response` before `this.setState`. If something is wrong with it you can set an `invalid` state or something like this and based on this show whatever you need. Also change `http` to `https` in your `fetch` request (it's not related to the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A try/ catch block could work.

Wrap the call in the try block and put any error handling code you want in the catch block.

This way if the user types in "New Jork", the call will fail and enter the catch block. (You could also use .then/.catch instead as fetch returns a promise, up to you)

You should also check the response before setting it to the state, put something like this after response;

```
if (!response.ok) {
      return "INPUT ERROR";
    }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm looking in to this try right now. I do have another question though. I have if(city) {do this}... There is not way to check all ready there like && city===(a city...?)..

I think i wrote that i bit messy but i hope you understand. But i do guess its hard to check if city exists before trying to fetch the API?

Comment: I think I get what you mean. Basically check if the city exists before making the request to get the weather of it, right?------Yeah the only way to do that is to have all the cities stored somewhere (either locally or from another API), then check them and then make the request.  -----Would probably avoid all that though. Hope that answered what you meant.

Comment: I used the Catch like above comment said, and handle that along with all other errors :)